# Caldroid does not refresh

Tags: android, android-fragments, caldroid

I have put Caldroid inside my activity with this code in `onCreate` method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    app_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "custom_font.ttf");
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    caldroidFragment = new CaldroidFragment();
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        caldroidFragment.restoreStatesFromKey(savedInstanceState,
                "CALDROID_SAVED_STATE");
    } else {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(CaldroidFragment.MONTH, calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
        args.putInt(CaldroidFragment.YEAR, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        args.putBoolean(CaldroidFragment.ENABLE_SWIPE, true);
        args.putBoolean(CaldroidFragment.SIX_WEEKS_IN_CALENDAR, true);
        args.putInt(CaldroidFragment.START_DAY_OF_WEEK, CaldroidFragment.MONDAY);
        caldroidFragment.setArguments(args);
    }
    FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    t.replace(R.id.calendar_holder, caldroidFragment, FRAGMENT_TAG);
    t.commit();
    fragmentMounted = true;
    CaldroidListener listener = new CaldroidListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSelectDate(Date date, View view) {
            Intent k = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DateActivity.class);
            k.putExtra(TIME, date.getTime());
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(k);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChangeMonth(int month, int year) {
            if (marker != null) {
                marker.stopWorking();
            }
            marker = new DateMarker(MainActivity.this, month, year);
            marker.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClickDate(Date date, View view) {
            // do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onCaldroidViewCreated() {
            // do nothing
        }

    };
    caldroidFragment.setCaldroidListener(listener);
}
```

As you notice, there is a `Thread` being called inside listener every time user switches to other month. This thread accesses database and marks dates which have events.

NOTE: this is just inner sample of code inside run method of that thread.

```
// more code above
if (MainActivity.dbHelper.getNotesOnDate(date).size() == 0) {
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            activity.caldroidFragment.setBackgroundResourceForDate(R.color.SeaGreen, date);
            activity.caldroidFragment.setTextColorForDate(R.color.white, date);
            activity.caldroidFragment.refreshView();
        }
    });
}
//more code under
```

I start another activity for user to log in while all this loads. The problem is only markings that are made BEFORE replacing fragment with holder view in `onCreate` method. How can I refresh `caldroidFragment` after replacing it with its holder? `refreshView()` seems not to be working after placing it.

**EDIT**: I did research and I notice Caldroid is using app V4 `Fragment`. I tried to detach and reattach it to get refresh effect but I only got `NullPointerException` while trying to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, do not use Java's `Date` class, it does not work right.

Use Joda's `DateTime`. Caldroid works fine with it. Also, I found minor bug in my database access, but it should have worked even though it was there.